# Can Interjections interrupt between parts of a sentence?

Tags: interjections

For example,

> I’m really surprised by, wow, your action.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: No, it isn't because "wow" shows surprise first, then, the idea. Wow, I'm really surprised by your action.

Comment: @Lambie You mean any interjections cannot be between parts of a sentence?

Comment: Note, however, that plenty of actual speech is ungrammatical to begin with.

Comment: I’m like wow by your action. Wow, what have you done. If you say "I'm like wow by your action", it is no longer an interjection. interjections interrupt speech or precede speech. They do not come in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search gave links explaining they can be both at the beginning, and in the middle.

[https://prowritingaid.com/](https://prowritingaid.com/grammar/1000160/Should-I-use-comma-after-interjections-#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20interjections%20include%20oh,a%20unique%20part%20of%20speech.&text=They%20can%20also%20be%20used%20at%20the%20beginning,the%20middle%20of%20other%20sentences.) states this quite well with examples of both.

The *'opinion'* of the reader/writer and the speaker/audience is apparently left to decide what is grammatically correct for themselves.

However, in your example, I am left as the reader to believe the interjection **wow** is emphatic or especially emotionally expressed and should be used with an exclamation point. In which case it shouldn't be used in the middle with a comma, but rather at the beginning of the sentence followed by a comma with the exclamation point at the end of the entire sentence. So no, the use of wow in the middle is like a pothole in the street.